# Height of iframe's content is 0 when in a display none container

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, height

In Firefox and IE, the height of the content in an iframe is 0 if the iframe is within a container that has `display: none;` on it. The height is correctly given in Chrome.

Example when container has `display: none;` http://jsfiddle.net/8g957vhd/ (height 0px)

Example when container has `display: block;` http://jsfiddle.net/kf06nwwt/ (correct height)

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only 'solution' I've found to this is to either:

- Only hide the iframe's parent after the the height has been calculated
- Use `visibility: hidden;` instead to hide it (along with `position: absolute;` or `height: 0;` to ensure it takes up no space on the page